# Cannot read a row from SQL which has been inserted few seconds back from other web-service

Tags: python, mysql, sql, apache-kafka

So, I've micro-service setup of 2 Web services which communicates through means of kafka queue.

First Web service is performs insertion of row and updated the recently updated row. And as soon as update is done on SQL row, 1st micro services publishes message with some processed information to the kafka queue and second process is listening to this kafka queue.

Now, as soon message is published, meanwhile other information is performed. That is 1 request represents batch of input files to be processed. If first request received 5 input files then makes 5 entry in db and produces 5 messages to be pushed to kafka queue.

And batch is being processed in for loop.

Now! After few seconds (nearly 1 seconds), second web service polls the message which is been pushed to queue by first process. And second web service validates whether entry is present in SQL DB or not for the respective message (querying with some uuid present in message which is also present in DB)

Now, when 2nd service is trying to read the row which is been inserted by first web service, it unable to do so. It results in empty result set but query does exist in DB.

It only happens when there's large batch is being processed by first process and happened on load testing.

In first and second Web service, I've been using single instantiated SQL connection object which I'd mentioned in setting.py of Django for first Web service.

Second web service is simple polling script which instantiated SQL connection object only once and been using it in thorough infinite while loop of polling.

I tried adding sleep before pulling messages, still didn't do a charm.

Can anyone help me out in this?

Language: both the services are written in python. Where first micro service is Django web service and second micro service is just a polling script.

Here's sample code to first microservice:

```
requested_batch_list = request_serializer.data
for batch_input_file in requested_batch_list:
    do_some_entry_on_request_tracking_table()
    do_some_processing()
    update_request_tracking_table()
    publish_message_to_kafka_topic()
```

sample pseudo code for micro service 2

```
while True:
    message = self.pull_message_from_kafka(1)
    request_batch_id = message['request_id']
    perfrom_select_query(request_batch_id)
    do_something()
    done_processing()
```

Time Logs at First microservice:
update_request_tracking_table() ---> 13-04-2020 18:08:59,15
publish_message_to_kafka_topic() ---> 13-04-2020 18:08:59,208

Time logs for second microservice:
pull_message_from_kafka(1) ---> 13-04-2020 18:09:25,863
perfrom_select_query()  ---> 13-04-2020 18:09:25,864

And also, How possily db.commit() will help? I am not using transactions yet.

what possibly could went wrong with this setup?

Comment: You need to post a [mcve]. Did the first service call `db.commit()`?

Comment: hello @Barmar I've added pseudo code and time logs. Also, I might have been missing some best practises like publishing message in a loop, not after all the entries for batches are updated in DB and then publish all message at once. Although, what could go wrong? Yes. I didn't use db.commit() since I was not using Transactions.